# How to check condition in qq ajax file uploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to check drop down list must select a value before open a file using qq ajax file uploader.
How to check this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let initially the upload control be disabled. Put the code below in document.ready()

:

```
$("#dropdown_Id").change(function () {
                         if($("#dropdown_Id").val()!=0)//Assuming selected value of dropdownlist initially is 0
                           {
                             //Code to enable upload control
                              }
                            else
                            {
                              //Code to disable upload control
                             }
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind event to dropdown and depending on that change disabled/enabled state of uploader